# Generated image pixels not shown in UV/Image Editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv-image-editor

I used Python to generate an image texture which consists of a single row of colored pixels. The pixels each encode the color of a star, of which there are 119,617 (modeled as a particle system).

Trouble is, when I open the generated image in the UV/Image Editor panel, the pixels colors don't show.

I can see their alpha values if I switch to Alpha-only view mode, and I can click on the pixels to get their RGBA values (which are correct, and which are accompanied by a square showing the color itself).

Is there anything that might cause this issue? A setting that I can change to correct it?

Thank you in advance for any insight you can give!

Comment: Perhaps share your python code (or a cut down version that still triggers the problem) so that others have a chance of replicating it and tracking down thr problem.

Comment: Perhaps this is as simple as being that the unusual extreme dimensions of the image (119617 x 1 pixels) are beyond what the Image Editor is capable of handling.

Comment: That seems possible. I changed the image texture to be 347-by-345 pixels, and it shows up fine like that in the UV/Image Editor. Although, to be fair, I also changed the settings of the image itself, including its format (now EXR) and its bit depth (from the default 8 bit to 32 bit). I'll check again if the 119,617-by-1 image might show up now and update this post if it does. It's good to know if it there is a chance that it is a software limitation.